# Why is std::unordered_set rehashed even if the load factor limit is not broken?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-set

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace),

> Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.

In addition, [[unord.req]/15](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#15) has similar rules:

> The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not affect the validity of iterators if `(N+n) <= z * B`, where `N` is the number of elements in the container prior to the insert operation, `n` is the number of elements inserted, `B` is the container's bucket count, and `z` is the container's maximum load factor.

However, consider the following example:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> s;
    s.emplace(1);
    s.emplace(42);
    std::cout << s.bucket_count() << ' ';
    std::cout << (3 > s.max_load_factor() * s.bucket_count()) << ' ';
    s.emplace(2);
    std::cout << s.bucket_count() << ' ';
}
```

With GCC 8.0.1, it outputs

```
3 0 7
```

This means after emplacing 2, a rehashing occurs though the new number of elements (3) is **not** greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()` (note the second output is 0). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rehash condition is changed since [Issue 2156](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2156). Before the change, a rehash occurs when the new number of elements is **no less than** `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`, and it becomes "greater than" after the change.

GCC 8.0.1 does not implement this change. There is already a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87135), and it has been fixed in GCC 9.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the fact that the `bucket_count()` has changed with the invalidation of iterators. Iterators are only invalidated in case of rehash, which will not be one if new number of elements is less than or equal to `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()` (btw if `size()>max_load_factor()*bucket_count()` rehashing *can* occur, but doesn't have to).

As this was not the case in your example, no rehashing occurred and iterators remain valid. However, the bucket count had to be increased to accommodate the new element.

I experimented a bit (expanding on your code) with Mac OSX's clang, which kept the iterators valid even after `rehash(size())` (which did change the element's bucket association, tested directly by iterating over the buckets and printing their contents).

Comment: If you change 42 to 41 in my example, and output `s.bucket(41)` before and after `s.emplace(2)`, you'll [observe two different results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5elmQsrTp5D80toY). Doesn't this mean there is indeed a rehashing?

Comment: The *bucket index* (which `bucket()` returns) can/does change, even if the bucket itself remains the same.

Comment: Look at [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nVxXvV7YpIxxlugH), the index of bucket of 1 and that of 40 are the same before `s.emplace(2)`, but become different after `s.emplace(2)`, how do you explain that?

Answer (score 2):

From **26.2.7 Unordered associative containers**

> The number of buckets is automatically increased as elements are added to an unordered associative container, *so that the average number of elements per bucket is kept below a bound*.
>
> ```
> b.load_factor()           Returns the average number of elements per bucket.
>
> b.max_load_factor()       Returns a positive number that the container attempts 
>                           to keep the load factor less than or equal to. The container
>                           automatically increases the number of buckets as necessary
>                           to keep the load factor below this number.
> ```

I agree, the first part of description of `max_load_factor` suggests that the load factor could reach that value, but in the second part and in the foregoing quote it's clearly stated that the load factor will be kept below this number. So, you have found a mistake in cppreference.

In your code, without rehashing, after the third insertion your would have `s.load_factor` equal to `s.max_load_factor()`.

EDIT: To answer changes in the question i checked available to me VS implementation of `unordered_set`, it is implemented as

> ```
> // hash table -- list with vector of iterators for quick access
> ```

and then you ask for an iterator, using e.g. `lower_bound`, you get iterator to the list element, which doesn't get invalidated by rehashing. So, it agrees with [unord.req]/15.

Comment: But [\[unord.req\]/15](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#15) agrees with the description of cppreference.

Comment: @xskxzr yes, and iterators don't get invalidated after this operation. Interesting discovery:)