# Predict resize/rehash of std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map

Tags: c++

Is it possible to reliably predict when an insert to std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map will resize the underlying storage and rehash the items?

My program maintains an unordered_set of items that constantly grows, but some  items may become 'expired', and I can remove those from the set to save space. A good time to do it is just before inserting an item, in case the insert will cause the set to resize and rehash. The set will anyway need to scan all of its elements and I may even prevent it from resizing).

But so far I did not find a way to predict a resize that will work across implementations of the standard library. The code below exposes differences between Microsoft's implementation and libstdc++.

```
std::unordered_set<int> set;
for (int i=0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    size_t bucketsBefore = set.bucket_count();
    set.emplace(i);
    size_t bucketsAfter = set.bucket_count();
    bool resized = bucketsAfter > bucketsBefore;
    if (resized)
        printf("Size from %zu to %zu, buckets from %zu to %zu.\n", set.size() - 1, set.size(), bucketsBefore, bucketsAfter);
}
```

When compiled with MSVC in Windows, this prints

```
Size from 8 to 9, buckets from 8 to 64.
Size from 64 to 65, buckets from 64 to 512.
Size from 512 to 513, buckets from 512 to 1024.
```

When compiled with g++ in Linux, this prints

```
Size from 0 to 1, buckets from 1 to 3.
Size from 2 to 3, buckets from 3 to 7.
Size from 6 to 7, buckets from 7 to 17.
Size from 16 to 17, buckets from 17 to 37.
Size from 36 to 37, buckets from 37 to 79.
Size from 78 to 79, buckets from 79 to 167.
Size from 166 to 167, buckets from 167 to 337.
Size from 336 to 337, buckets from 337 to 709.
Size from 708 to 709, buckets from 709 to 1493.
```

In terms of load factor this means that Microsoft implementation will resize the set when load factor would exceed 1, but libstdc++ -- when load factor reaches 1.

Now I'm wondering what's a good way around it. There are options.

1. Remove expired items after a resize. The more robust option, but this way you can never prevent a resize. That's what I do now.
2. Remove expired items when libstdc++ would perform the resize. Not too bad of an idea, but if there exists a third implementation that would resize even earlier, e.g., when load factor reaches 1-epsilon, then for that implementation I would never remove expired items. Given that Microsoft and libstdc++ already treat the load factor differently, I don't see a reason why such third implementation may not appear. Or is there a reason?

Comment: Why not compute what the load factor is at run time and use that for when you need to check if you can remove expired items?

Comment: There is also [load_factor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/load_factor) and [max_load_factor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/max_load_factor)

Comment: Have you done any profiling to show that set resizing is a major bottleneck in the program? you are basically trying to create a garbage collector. So, if it is really necessary, automatically call after every 100 inserts (or whatever). Given that implementations have a lot of freedom in implementation details as long as they meet the interface contract, there will never be a truly "portable" way to do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have to be consistent with how the set implementation uses the load factor when deciding when to resize. Msvcrt and libstdc++ already use them in a different way, and that's what my question is about. The risk is the following: my check would tell the resize would not happen while some existing or future implementation of the set would actually resize. In this case, I'll never remove expired items.

Comment: @mhhollomon Not a major bottleneck, and I now I just run the 'garbage collection' after a resize. But being able to reliably detect a resize would be an improvement, even if a small one. In terms of the implementation, the interface of unordered_set/unordered_map (between having at all a notion of a bucket, not invalidating references on rehash, etc) already implies a particular implementation, so it could be nice if the libraries went one extra small step and treated the load factor consistently.

Comment: Maybe related: [Why is std::unordered_set rehashed even if the load factor limit is not broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49333414/5376789)

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks. The link contains the explanation of why I see different behaviour.

Comment: Just to recap the link given by @xskxzr. Requirements on load factor and resizing have changed in due to Issue2156 of c++17. My version of mscrt coming from vs2017 implements the post-2156 behaviour, and my version of libstdc++ coming with g++ 7.3 implements the pre-2156 behaviour version.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `boost::intrusive::unordered_set` and do rehashing yourself based on load factor and amount of `expired` items.